# Self-reference Rmd file in interactive mode

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I'm interested in attaching metadata to saved objects, including the script that saved the data. Towards that end, I would like to catch the name of a script in the script itself.

When I have an Rmarkdown document as below and I knit it, the code chunk results in the name of the script that generated it. This is exactly what I want, however, this only works when the document is being knit. I would like to do the same if I'm executing the chunk in Rstudio in an interactive way.

````
---
title: "test"
author: "me"
date: "21/09/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
if (interactive()) {
  # Get the same as non-interactive version?
} else {
  as.character(sys.call(1))[2]
}
```
````

Does anybody know how to catch the name of the current Rmarkdown script in an interactive session?

Comment: This sounds hard... my understanding (that is, best guess) is that interactively commands are sent to the console for execution by the editor (RStudio, in this case) - so the R session itself has no way of knowing whether the command was copy/pasted, sent by RStudio from some file, typed manually, etc.

Comment: Note, for example, that you can access `YAML` metadata using `rmarkdown::metadata`, but this also won't be available interactively, as the YAML isn't parsed by the interactive R session. And your file might not even be saved yet. I think your best bet might be to define a title/name/id in R code early in the document.

Comment: Yes I was afraid it was going to be hard. I was kind of hoping that since `getwd()` gives different results if executed in a code chunk than at the console, there might be some way to distinguish the console from a code chunk. (At least when the .Rmd doesn't live in the current directory).

Comment: Playing around a bit more, `rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()` seems to know whether it is being executed in a chunk or in the console. The downside is that it reports a path to a temporary file.

Comment: If there's an answer, I think that's the right track. There won't be standard R or even `knitr` commands for this, but `rstudioapi` seems like a good place to start. I mean, RStudio definitely knows what's going on, the question is whether or not that's available to the R session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()` gives you information (a list) about the current file opened in the RStudio source editor. The path of the file is stored in the `path` element of the list.

BTW, for non-interactive R sessions, `knitr::current_input()` gives you the path to the source document being knitted (your `sys.call(1)` approach sounds clever, though).