# When inside an R library, getting the path of the original file calling the library?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, filepath

Short: When inside an R library, how do you get the path of the **original** file calling the library?

Long: I am building a library for creating ggplots according to my organization's style. Currently, to apply the style one just needs to add `+ mypackage::addstyle` to the code for a plot. These plots later end up on slides, and we often forget where we put the script that made it. In order to aid in reproducible research, I would like to add a caption to each figure that states where the plot came from. E.g. `W:/Important Project/script27.R`

There are multiple ways to get the path of the script inside of the script. For example, [`rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452086/getting-path-of-an-r-script/57522527#57522527). However, when I embed those commands inside I get the library I get `W:/mypackage/R/style.R`, not `W:/Important Project/script27.R`.

Comment: Your attempt to use `rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext` will not work for anybody not using RStudio. I don't know if that is your intent, or how many like me do not use RStudio regularly.

Comment: If you just type commands on the console or run then in RStudio without `source()` the commands don't actually have to be from a script file at all. You can just copy/paste code. Code doesn't always have a source. (Even an RStudio editor window might not have been saved yet and doesn't have a path). This really isn't a very practical thing to accomplish. Is there a general pipeline you are using to run this code that's more controlled?

Comment: @MyFlick Could you suggest an alternative pipeline? I tried teunbrand's suggestion and I just got "console", presumably for the reading you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63993737/self-reference-rmd-file-in-interactive-mode) some time ago. I ended up settling on [this function](https://github.com/teunbrand/datastamp/blob/master/R/current_document.R):

```
get_current_document <- function() {
  
  if (interactive()) {
    
    if (rstudioapi::isAvailable()) {
      
      script <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()
      
      if (nchar(script$path) == 0) {
        script <- script$id
      } else {
        script <- script$path
      }
      
    } else {
      
      script <- "#console"
      
    }
    
    script <- gsub("^#console$", "console", script)
    
  } else {
    
    script <- as.character(sys.call(1))[2]
    
  }
  
  return(script)
}
```

Which in your case would work like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(caption = get_current_document())
```

[image]

However, the function isn't robust against all types of cases. I know that the `testthat` and `reprex` packages create temporary R sessions that the function isn't able to locate. I'd also love to know a better way.